# How to add back button arrow functionality in navigation bar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation

I am beginner programmer and just resent started android developing.
Watched many answers and couldn't find answer witch would fit for me.
I have added back arrow button in my action bar, but couldn't figure out how to add navigation to first loaded screen.

> MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    if (actionBar != null){
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    final ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Back button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.container_text);
    Fragment fragment = null;

    if (id == R.id.nav_about) {

        fragment = DemoFragment.newInstance("about");
        text.setText("1");
    }  else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {

        fragment = DemoFragment.newInstance("nav settings");
    }
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
            .commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

> DemoFragment.java

```
public class DemoFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String TEXT = "text";

public static DemoFragment newInstance(String text) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(TEXT, text);
    DemoFragment fragment = new DemoFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_demo, container, false);
    String text = getArguments().getString(TEXT);
    return view;
}
```

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

> app_bar_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="lt.simbal.drawer.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/container"
    layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

> content_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="lt.simbal.drawer.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/container_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="MAIN_ACTIVITY" />
```

> fragment_demo.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

> nav_header_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="Android Studio"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="android.studio@android.com" />
```

> activity_main_drawer.xml

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_about"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="@string/about" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="@string/settings" />
</group>
```

Comment: vote down cause you dont know what you want to do. Make toast or go to previous or next activity

Comment: I need to go to my activity, when I select fragment in my navigation drawer. With back button I need to reach my activity_main.

Comment: In your DemoFragment, onCreateView() add line setHasOptionsMenu(true);

Comment: @Stanojkovic: Still no result. maybe I could send you my code or maybe post all in this question? I guess with all code you could tell me what's wrong :/

Comment: Add all code here, of all activities and your manifest file.

Comment: @Stanojkovic: Added all code, even with my NavigationView layout and even other layouts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101882/discussion-between-stanojkovic-and-jonasseputis).

Comment: @Stanojkovic: Thank you for your help, I changed my program structure and everything is working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call **setHomeAsUpIndicator** & **setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled**

> Set an alternate drawable to display next to the icon/logo/title when
>   DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP is enabled. This can be useful if you are using
>   this mode to display an alternate selection for up navigation, such as
>   a sliding drawer.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

if (actionBar != null)
{
   ......
   actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //Set this to true if selecting "home" returns up by a single level in your UI rather than back to the top level or front page.
   actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.Your_Icon); // set a custom icon for the default home button
}
```

**Now**

For this handling need to override **`onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`** method in your Activity .

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.home:

       // Add your LOGIC Here
        break;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: He set that in his code. He need only to set intent in his R.id.home.

Comment: @Stanojkovic Thanks .

Answer (score 4):

Alright make sure u do declare activity layout as below -

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
    <!-- The meta-data element is needed for versions lower than 4.1 -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Now in every activity add below code

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
// Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
case android.R.id.home:
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: good! and if you don't use fragments, you even don't need in any code, xml is enough

Answer (score 3):

add below code in onCreate

---

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if (actionBar != null){
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.back_dark);
}
```

---

`R.drawable.back_dark` is back button image

remove this `actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);` from your code

---

***EDITED:*** found one thing, change below method

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    //if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        //return true;
    //}
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Back button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

***otherwise your all code is perfect! no need to change naythig***

---

### @JonasSeputis: i have use your activity and run in android device its showing toast *"Back button clicked"* check below code and comment other code for sometime

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }

        /*DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        final ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0);
            }
        });*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        //int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        /*if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }*/
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            case android.R.id.home:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Back button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove your switch statement from onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)  an put R.id.home in your if logic as you do it previously.

Comment: @Stanojkovic: android.R.id.home used when click on action bar icon R.id.home used when its id from xml file. so whatever i write in answer is correct

Comment: To show a toast try this Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Back button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: I've never say that your answer is wrong or incorect.

Comment: @Stanojkovic: r you reading answer or just commenting every where without reading?

Comment: when the View is changed to fragment, Back button doesn't show Toast anymore :/

Answer (score 2):

In your

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){ 
    if (id == android.R.id.home){
    // add intent to class you wish to navigate
    Intent i = new Intent("com.your.package.classname");
    startActivity(i);

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just add this line in 
`onCreate`:

`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`